# Saga doesn't end when canceled

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I have a polling saga which runs every 10 seconds.  When an UPDATE_DEPLOYMENT request is made I cancel any running polling saga, clear state, and trigger a new poll (which should now poll a new rest endpoint since the site_location value in state is also updated by UPDATE_DEPLOYMENT).

This doesn't seem to work.  The currently running polling saga runs to completion without being canceled, eventually reporting a failure because it starts to hit the new rest url requesting components which only existed on the old url due to the site_location state being changed midway through it's run.

Here is the main saga (a different saga is responsible for updating the site_location state when UPDATE_DEPLOYMENT is sent to stay in keeping with standard architecture all our GUIs use)

```
export function* watchPollRequest() {
  let pollTask;

  while (true) {
    const action = yield take([POLL, UPDATE_DEPLOYMENT, REPORT_SUCCESS, REPORT_FAILURE]);

     switch (action.type) {
       case REPORT_SUCCESS:
       case REPORT_FAILURE:
         pollTask = undefined;
         break;
       case UPDATE_DEPLOYMENT:
         if (pollTask) {
            cancel(pollTask);
            pollTask = undefined;
         }
         yield put(clearSummaryData());
         yield put(poll()); 
       case POLL:
         if (pollTask) {
           // only need one poll at a time
           break;
          }
          pollTask = yield fork(onPollRequest);
          break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Testing shows that no matter when the cancel runs the old poll runs to completion without being cancled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem after writing this.  It was a stupid typo, I'm missing my yield in front of the cancel method.